# git-svn stops with no error message when trying to clone

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm running the git-svn clone command against the subversion server as follows:

git svn clone svn: --no-metadata -A users.txt --stdlayout ~/temp

The message 'Checked through r0000' appears and the revision number increases up to r8200 and then pauses. After about 30 seconds the commands prompt re-appears and I have the makings of a git repository in the temp directory but it contains no actual source code files.

How can I get more information on what is happening?

I have tried the git-svn from both a windows and a linux client. On windows it is version 1.8.1, on linux it is 1.7.10.4

Comment: `git svn` is awfully slow on windows, just use linux. You can see whether it's doing something by looking at the logs on the svn server, if you have access to. You won't see the files in your "temp" directory while the import is in progress, as it's only at the end that it's gonna make a `git checkout`. You should still be able to see the content of your git repo using `gitk --all`

Comment: yes I found git svn very slow on windows which is why I switched to linux. However they both stop at the same point. If I try gitk there is an error message 'Error reading commits: fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD''. The git-svn process has stopped at this point so it will never do a git checkout. Something is causing it to fail before hand

Comment: I suggest you use the `-r` argument of `git svn fetch` or `git svn clone` to get the revisions by chunks, and see at which revision the problem occurs. You should have a valid Git repos at the end of each step. If you can see which commit is failing to import, inspect it, maybe there is something special in it that makes `git svn` fail.

Comment: it doesn't seem to matter what revision number or range I add to the -r option, I just end up with a very empty looking git repository in ~/temp

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error/behaviour and eventually i realized that the svn path i used in my command included the `\trunk` folder. Once i used the parent folder instead it started to work.

Comment: Thank you for this. This project is long gone now so I have no way to verify your answer so I'll just have to +1 rather than accept.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because the target local dir where it was trying to write already existed (for my `svn co` that I hope I won't have to use!).